# How to mock default exported function in Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs

In class that i want to test i am importing function like this :

```
import overflow from './components/overflow-vertical';
```

and call it here:

```
this.overflow = overflow(this.containerElement, this);
```

And the implementation of this overflow looks like this:

```
export default function render(container: HTMLElement, observer: IOverflowObserver){
      return overflow(container, new VerticalStrategy(), observer) };
```

How can i mock this overflow call in my test class using Jest?

Comment: Why dont you just explizit define it like `yourObj.overflow = () => {}`

Comment: I am not the one who wrote this code. I wanted to check if it could be done without rewriting existing functionality.